# AttributeError at / 'str' object has no attribute 'objects'

Tags: django

I am new to Django. I am working on a project that uses weather API to get the weather.Everything was working fine until models.py was made and imported city on views.py

I use ver. 1.11.13

models.py

```
  from __future__ import unicode_literals

  from django.db import models

  class city(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

  def __str__(self):
      return self.name

  class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural ='cities'
```

views.py ( Error comes  at cities = city.objects.all())

```
import requests

from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import city

def index(request):
  url= 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={}& units=imperial&appid=e1a2ef38103d2e572d316e38452e2acd'
  city = 'Lucknow'

  cities = city.objects.all()

  weather_data =[]

  for city in cities:


    r= requests.get(url.format(city)).json()


    city_weather = {
         'city':city.name ,
         'temperature' :r['main']['temp'],
         'description' :r['weather'][0]['description'],
         'icon' :r['weather'][0]['icon'] ,
    }
    weather_data.append(city_weather)

    print(weather_data)

context = {'weather_data' : city_weather}

return render(request,'weather/weather.html', context)
```

Comment: You have overwritten `city` with `city = 'Lucknow'`. So rename the variable. Furthermore Python style guidlines say to let classes start with an uppercase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `index` function, you write:

```
def index(request):
    url= 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={}& units=imperial&appid=e1a2ef38103d2e572d316e38452e2acd'
    city = 'Lucknow'

    cities = city.objects.all()
    # ...
```

As a result, you defined `city` here as a *locally* scoped variable, and with a string value. A quick fix is to rename the string, like:

```
def index(request):
    url= 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={}& units=imperial&appid=e1a2ef38103d2e572d316e38452e2acd'
    city_ = 'Lucknow'

    cities = city.objects.all()
    # ...
    # use city_ for the string element
```

But nevertheless, a class typically starts with an uppercase, so I would advice to rename your class `City` instead of `city`.

Furthermore I find it weird that you defined this string, since nowehere in the view, you are supposed to use it. The `url.format(..)` should probably use the `city.name` of the `City` object in the queryset.

Comment: Thank you that Helped !! another quick help why does the value prints like 'city': u'New Delhi', 'icon': u'50n', 'temperature': 98.6, 'description': u'dust'}]    why does that u appears before the values ?

Comment: @AdarshBahadur: you probably print `{{weather_data}}`. Then it prints a *representation* of the entire dictionary. You should use `{{ weather_data.city }}`, `{{ weather_data.description }}`, to access the individual members.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for your time !

Comment: Completely removing this city = 'Lucknow' helped. I used this to test my app initially.

Comment: @AdarshBahadur: ah, then the issue is now resolved. Although I would advice to rename your classes such that these start with an uppercase. It is recommended by PEP-8: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: Yeah I made those changes too. Thank you.

Comment: I also found this issue. And class name is in uppercase only eg: Lucknow

Answer (score 3):

Solve this issue.

For dynamic table name you can use like

```
 table_name = 'MyTable'
 model = getattr(YOURAPP.models, table_name)
 model.objects.all()
```